# Android change default button background colors

Tags: android, button, layout

I was trying to change the button background colors (default, pressed and focus), but I couldn't find a good way. I have read many posts about styling a buuton, but unfortunately these were post to create a compete new style. I want to keep everything the same except for the background colors.

I prefer using xml because I'm using a single layout for multiple activities. I was also looking for a solution that works for  android 4.0 and up and below 4.0.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the default button color without losing the shadow, Then I recommend changing the style of the required button.

You can simply do this by adding this line to the button tag

```
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
```

Sample code will look like this

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:text="Rate now"/>
```

now change the colorAccent to the desired color in the color.xml located under res->values->colors.xml file.

```
<color name="colorAccent">your color here</color>
```

you can visit the official developer page to get more information [Styling buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `button_style.xml` with the settings you want for your button like the example below, and place this file inside the `drawable` folder under the `res` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/MyButtonDarkGray"
                android:endColor="@color/MyButtonDarkGray"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@color/Gray" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/Green"
                android:startColor="@color/Green"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@color/Gray" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/green_leaf_top"
                android:startColor="@color/green_leaf_bottom"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@color/Gray" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Now, in your `styles.xml` under the `res\values` folder, add

```
<style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_style</item>
</style>
```

This style will work for all your buttons only.

NOTE: The colors are defined separately in `res\values\colors.xml`, you can use your own colors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an xml for changing colors based on the states of button:
Create a drawable resource as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
</selector>
```

In java code set the drawable resource as below:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mydrawable));
```

In xml set the drawable as background of the button in the xml:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/mydrawable" />
```

NOTE: you can either set in java code or in xml.

Comment: @android:color/red,yellow and blue are not recognized

Comment: They will only work for API 11 and above. I need is for API 5

Comment: Not sure about any solution for pre API 11.  you can ignore this being done for pre API 11 mobiles and perform this only for post API 11 mobiles